# RethinkDB data structure

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I'm new to RethinkDb and NoSql

1: what I learned is Document base db is data driven, what ever data is coming you just put it in db. Thats is main benefit of it. You don't need to built schema or structure of your data, data makes its own structure

e.g  initially data is as follows

```
{
 name:
 address: 
 phone: 
}
```

later

```
{
 name: 
 {
  firstname:
  lastname:
 }
 address: 
  {
   address1:
   address2:
  }
 phone:
  {
   phone1:
   phone2:
  }
}
```

Both of data is in the document, you have to adjust your application to it.

Do I understand it correctly. Does this approach is correct ?

2: I'm making an hospital management application. I want to know how much deep i can create a document

e.g

```
{
 id:
 patient name:
 age: 
 patient_activity:
  {
   lab: 
    [
     { 
      test_name:
      test_results:
     }
     ....
     ....
    ]
    xray: 
    [
     { 
      xray:
      comments:
     }
     ....
     ....
    ]
    ....
    ....
  }
```

patient name, age would remain same for every visit, but their activities like lab tests, prescription, medicines, operation etc can be of multiple for each visit.

So my question is How much deep level i can go and when to break data into multiple documents

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, according to [doc](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/troubleshooting/), ReQL’s nesting depth is limited to 20 levels.

Comment: @Jawad it depends. For example, in case when you are trying to `filter` table by nested fields, if will reduce performance. Same for subscription on changefeeds. I recommend to keep nesting level < 8-10. You can, for example, move some fields to different table and bind data by id (like foreign keys in SQL databases).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on data modeling](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/data-modeling/) gives on overview of various models and their pros and cons:

> There are two ways to model relationships between documents in RethinkDB:
>
> - By using embedded arrays.
> - By linking documents stored in multiple tables (similar to traditional relational database systems).